# changing the order from asc to desc or vice versa on click table header react

Tags: reactjs

maybe it's simple but I'm not able to understand the solutions I found...
I have a ready function that changes the order of the columns when I click on the header, but I would like to make the second click reverse the order.

the function that is working...

```
  function handleHeaderClick(clickedHeader) {
    const newdata = [...data].sort((a, b) => (a[clickedHeader] > b[clickedHeader] ? 1 : -1));
    setdata((prevdata) => newdata);
  }
```

what am i trying to do...
I also tried doing var and let in the order and it didn't work

@edit 4 Solved Created useState for order
Solution...

```
const [order, setOrder] = useState(true);

  function handleHeaderClick(clickedHeader) {
    setOrder(!order);
    const newdata = props.data.sort((a, b) => {
      const x = a[clickedHeader];
      const y = b[clickedHeader];
      if (order && x > y) return -1;
      return 1;
    });
    props.setdata(newdata);
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  function handleHeaderClick(clickedHeader) {
    const order = !order;
```

> react-dom.development.js:4312 Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access
> 'order' before initialization at Object.handleHeaderClick [as onClick]

You're initializing `order` with the (opposite) of the value of `order` itself: the error message is self explanatory.

Comment: sorry I really don't understand, can you explain me? ty alot

Comment: Sure, you're welcome. With `const order = !order` you're trying to initialize a variable with the opposite of its own value, but what was that value in the first place, since you're declaring the variable in that moment? It's like telling you "give your yet to be painted new car the opposite of its own color": the compiler is telling it doesn't make sense. I get that you want to toggle `order` but you can't do it that way. [Here](https://blog.logrocket.com/creating-react-sortable-table/) of a sorted table in React. If I helped you, feel free to accept and upvote my answer.

Comment: For example: if `order` had already been initialized somewhere else before and had a false value, then `order = !order` (without `const`, with `const` your initializing it right in that moment, as a constant) it would make `order` true, and viceversa.

Comment: first, thanks for your attention... so for your solution I should create a useState and change it whenever I click on the header? or a global var?

Comment: You're using React: use useState, it will care about making the variable immutable, it will store it and manage it. Hooks in general are very very powerful.

Comment: Ok now my problem is with ternary, I edit the question

Comment: Please write in the question itself that you edited it, or mods will think I answered the wrong question.